# Attempting to display image using HTML

Tags: html

```
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>



        <div class="modal-body">
            <img id=image src="C:\Users\Alex Cornelius\PythonPros\COVwebpage\templates\COVStruct1.png" alt="Click on button"/>


            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close Image


                </button>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I've tried displaying an image in HTML but it doesn't seem to work. The image is even in the same folder as the HTML file. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Try providing in your question some more DOM elements that surround the <img> tag

Comment: A path on your local filesystem like `C:/` is never going to work as a URL. If it's in the same folder, just use the name: `src="COVStruct1.png"`. If it 's somewhere else, you need a proper URL, like `http://example.com/COVStruct1.png`.

Comment: If both files are in the same folder you only need the filename, in this case COVStruct1.png

Comment: I would recommend you  to take a look at absolute paths vs relative paths

Comment: I tried using COVStruct1.png but for some reason, that is not working either.

Comment: Try adding `file:///` before `C:` . that will solve the issue, but you don't need to add whole path if you're in same folder. just add `COVStruct1.png` as `src` of image

Answer (score 0):

To dispaly an image with img tag you can provide either **absolut path** or **relative path**.
An absolute path is full url of the image like this:
*https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656533498028-2d06ade429f0*.
A relative path is relative to the current path of your file ,in this case your html file.

ex:

```
folder1
     htmlFile.html
     img1.png
     folder2
          img2.png
folder3
     img3.png
```

relative path of *img1* will be just **img1.png** and path of *img2* will be **folder2/img2.png**.

To get *img3* we should go up one level from htmlFile.html to find folder3 which contains our image. go up translation is double dot *..* so path will be ***../folder3/img3.png***.